# Help please with chat!

Tags: support

I apology if I'm so eager to be part of the chat. I'm having problem to log in to chat. I already logged in chat but STILL I'm not able to see the chat field where I could type in my message! I've tried several times and even I believe have done everything just to see that message but still its nowhere to be found.I'm not sure if this is the right place to address my concern but I'm hoping guys to could help me out. THANKS in advance!

Comment: Try this link: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/7227/english-language-learners. See if it works.

Comment: @Rolan We're waiting for you in there. :-)

Comment: Hi guys, I opened the link you posted but still no field to type in my message?

Comment: At the bottom, it's asking me to log in? I'm already logged in that's why I can't figure out where to log in. I tried as what it is telling me but still the same it led me to a different link which I think not letting me to enter the chat.

Comment: @Rolan I guess that maybe you need to log in to chat too, beside ELL.

Comment: Guys, I apology for my eagerness to join the chat. I just really want to be part of the chat so I could meet and talk to everyone. I posted this yesterday and I just came back today. Hope someone can help me with my agony. THANKS guys!

Comment: I already logged in to chat too but still no field I could place my message.

Comment: Could you try the direct link again? http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/7227/english-language-learners

Comment: @snailplane Hi, I've tried that several times and still the same routine is happening. I'm asked to log in because according to the link the only way I could start with chat is me logging in? That's why I tried that but still it didn't give me the option to type it in my message or basically there's no type field I could put the message? Thanks for your reply, really appreciate it!

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for helping me. I'm able to see guys all of your posts. But before I can type my message like what I'm doing right now, I still need to click on question that I posted at the top? I'm not sure if this how it works? And Oh! one thing more, I'm just seeing my post but the last post by @snailplane not showing here. I hoping I didn't confuse you guys. THANKS

Comment: AND in addition to that when I go back to the thread, still I'm not able to see my post that I just made. Also I'm not sure guys if you guys can see what I'm posting right now! I really appreciate the effort guys that you're doing. Thanks again all I can say!

Comment: This is a blind guess, but is it possible by any chance that you disable JavaScript in your browser? I think you need to enable JavaScript to have the ELL's website and chat room work properly.

Comment: Rolan are you on a mobile device? Sometimes mobile chat doesn't play too nicely.

Comment: It's a shot in the dark, but I just made a room and invited you to it. Can you see that and respond?